# How to store multiple scroll positions for scrolling div element depending on active View in MultiView (asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

confusing title but the best way I can put it.

Basically I am currently using a single div with overflow:auto that contains different GridViews. The GridViews are swapped by using a MultiView with each indiviudal view containing a single GridView.

I would like to be able to store the scroll position of each view so that I can set the div's scroll position depending on the view that will be switched to.

Here is how my page is set up.

```
<div id="scrollingDiv" style="height:100%; overflow:auto;">
  <div id="gridWrap">

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
      <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
      </asp:View>

      <asp:View ID="view2" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridView2" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
      </asp:View>
    </asp:Multiview>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  </div>
</div>
```

So scrollingDiv will contain all the Views and will scroll for each one of the GridViews.

To switch between views I have a drop down connected to an

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (DownList.SelectedItem.Value)
    {

        case "view1":
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(view1);
            break;
        case "view2":
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(view2);
            break;
    }
}
```

I have been looking around and can't quite find something specific to my case. I would like to be able to use just the one overflow div but would understand if I had to make a separate overflow div for each view.

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and some hidden fields can help. Try this...

```
    <asp:Hiddenfield ID="hdnCurrentView" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Hiddenfield ID="hdnMultiView1Top" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Hiddenfield ID="hdnMultiView2Top" runat="server"/>
```

On backend, i.e., in your CS file set the current view in hidden field...

```
    protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (DownList.SelectedItem.Value)
        {
            case "view1":
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(view1);
                hdnCurrentView.Value = "View1";
                break;
            case "view2":
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(view2);
                hdnCurrentView.Value = "View2";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Then in your jQuery ready function,

```
    $().ready(function() {

        //for storing scroll position of each view in respective hiddenfields
        $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($("#hdnCurrentView").val() == "View1") {
             $("#hdnMultiView1Top").val($(window).scrollTop());
          }
          else if ($("#hdnCurrentView").val() == "View2") {
             $("#hdnMultiView2Top").val($(window).scrollTop());
          }
        });

        //for restoring scroll position on page load i.e., ready function in jQuery 
        if ($("#hdnCurrentView").val() == "View1") {
           $(window).scrollTop($("#hdnMultiView1Top").val());
        }
        else if ($("#hdnCurrentView").val() == "View2") {
           $(window).scrollTop($("#hdnMultiView2Top").val());
        }

    });
```

This would maintain the vertical scroll position for each multiview. If you want to maintain horizontal scroll positions too, have hidden fields for each view & use jQuery function given below. Left to you as an excercise...

```
    $(window).scrollLeft(value);
```

Happy Coding...;)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I was struggling with hiddenfields before but this worked out. I placed the functions for setting the scroll positions into 'function pageLoad' and it worked! Thanks again